# Spring graph layout with some predefined positions in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am using the networkx package and python3 to layout a simple graph. If I simply use the spring layout, the result is not as nice as it could be (if layouted by hand). So my idea was to fix the position of some nodes. Currently I use the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_path(['H0', 'S0', 'S1', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'H3'], color='green')
G.add_path(['H5', 'S4', 'S3', 'S2', 'S1', 'S0', 'H1'], color='red')
G.add_path(['H2', 'S7', 'S6', 'S8', 'S3', 'S4', 'H4'], color='blue')

#explicitly set some positions to make the drawing nice
fixed_pos = {'S1':(-1,0),'S5':(0,0), 'S6':(1,0), 'S3':(0,1)}
fixed_nodes = fixed_pos.keys()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=fixed_pos, fixed = fixed_nodes, scale=3)

nx.draw_networkx(G,pos, font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif')
plt.show()
```

The result I get looks like this:

[image]

So all the nodes with a fixed position get crammed arround 0.5,0.5! Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have something weird with one of your installations, or there's something a little different about the code you're running.

After copying and pasting your code exactly (python2.7), I get:[image]

So the nodes are where you specified.

Comment: If I use networkx 1.9 (newest version available in Debian) I get the bug I described in my question. With version 1.10 it works. Thanks for your answer, it has helped me!

Comment: Weird - I wasn't aware of this issue in 1.9.1.  Glad it helped.